# When creating a Datagrid programatically, how to add a column with a textbox with wrapping?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am creating a `DataGrid` programatically and I want to add a column that has a `TextBox` that has word-wrap enabled. I am able to do it in the `XAML` with the following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

But I can't see to figure out how to replicate this when creating the databases dynamically, this is my code so far (which doesn't compile at the moment):

```
var datagrid = new DataGrid();

datagrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn()
{
    Header = "Type",
    Width = new DataGridLength(200),
    // here I want to set FONT = 12 and
    // TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty = TextWrapping.Wrap
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Try to set `Style` property with 'Style=FindResource('key to the resourse')'

Comment: There is no such thing as STYLE in this context...

Comment: Sorry,i mean `datagrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()){ Style=FindResource('keyvalue')}`.

Comment: This doesn't compile ... and how would you apply that to my example?